# J2EE - Pass entity directly to WAR

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

This might be a very noob J2EE question... It's related to how EJB's talk with the "front-end" WAR in Glassfish (or any app server, I suppose).

A package called "EJB" has a class called "Car" - it is an @Entity and maps to a table in the database. Easy.

From what I see, the EJBs instantiate these Entity objects (e.g. instances of a Car) and fulfill RPC requests from the WAR/servlet.

Here's the problem/question... From what I've seen, most people make a "model" package that consists of a bunch of POJO classes that represent the interface between the EJBs and the WAR... This is annoying because now I have to write all of these POJOs by hand. E.g. a rewrite of the "Car" class + a translation from the Entity to the "model" class.

Is it not possible to send the Entity (JPA class) directly to the WAR from the EJB??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you often don't want to present all properties of the entity or you want to present combined information from several entities. That is why people want to have separate model classes, even though they are often the same.

The name "model" may come from "MVC - Model View Controller" and it's responsible to store data presented to the user.

There are some mapping tools like Dozer, which should automatically map entity objects to "model" objects.

Comment: Agreed - I'm sure it's related to the MVC which I'm quite familiar with. These are all good points which I started to come to after discussing this with others offline. I think another point (parallel to what you've mentioned) is that a bean might want to present information in a different format/view to the caller. In this case, the model, which is really an interface (not to be confused with Java's interface), could be very different than an entity. I'll definitely take a look at Dozer - thanks!